# Making a docker image that contains ogr compiled with modern spatialite

Tags: docker, gdal, spatialite

I'm trying to run an ogr2ogr command that requires a version of
GDAL that is built with new enough SpatiaLite to have the ST_MakeValid 
function---from [discussion groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spatialite-users/aD81OdmgV6U), this seem [to be 4.0+](https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html)

However, the version of gdal in [ubuntugis](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable) has what looks like a modern version of gdal

```
$ gdalinfo --version
GDAL 2.2.4, released 2018/03/19
```

And I have a modern spatialite:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libspatialite-dev spatialite-bin libspatialite7
... already installed

$ spatialite
SpatiaLite version ..: 4.3.0a   Supported Extensions:
```

but the `ogr2ogr` command does not seem to be compiled with the version of spatialite that is in the repos as a stand-alone binary, but rather something older.  (I cannot tell how to check which version it is compiled with, simply that [this command that succeeds when it is up to date, fails](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304439/command-line-tool-to-repair-self-intersection-in-geojson))

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y software-properties-common \
 && add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable -y && apt-get update \
 && apt-get install --yes gdal-bin curl \
 && curl -LKS 'https://github.com/OpenDataDE/State-zip-code-GeoJSON/raw/master/ks_kansas_zip_codes_geo.min.json' -o  ks_kansas_zip_codes_geo.min.json \ 
 && ogrinfo --version \ 
 && ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -dialect sqlite -sql "select ST_MakeValid(geometry),STATEFP10,ZCTA5CE10,GEOID10,CLASSFP10,MTFCC10,FUNCSTAT10,ALAND10,AWATER10,INTPTLAT10,INTPTLON10,PARTFLG10 from \"ks_kansas_zip_codes_geo.min\"" clean.json ks_kansas_zip_codes_geo.min.json
```

What can I change in the repos or how do I manually compile `gdal` to have a version of spatialite that contains the  `ST_MakeValid` function?

### Notes

Collecting search results that might be relevant:

- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157406/how-to-re-compile-ogrinfo-against-gdal-used-by-qgis?rq=1]
- http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildHints
- https://pastebin.com/iE4zwQTb
- https://github.com/GeographicaGS/Docker-GDAL2 This Docker image is not compiled against the correct libspatialite
- https://hub.docker.com/r/roblabs/gdal/ This Docker image is also not compiled against the correct libspatialite

#### Updates to dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update \ 
 && apt-get install -y software-properties-common \
 && add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable -y \
#    # INSTALLING GRASS DOES NOT SEEM HELPFUL
#       && add-apt-repository ppa:grass/grass-devel -y \
 && apt-get update \
 && apt-get install --yes curl git autoconf libtool \
#   # TRIED RTTOPO FROM HERE:
#   #   http://postgis.17.x6.nabble.com/Why-can-t-PostGIS-configure-find-libgeos-c-td3552982.html
#   # AND HERE:
#   #   https://gitlab.com/rttopo/rttopo
#   # DOES NOT SEEM FRUITFUL
#       apt-get install --yes libgeos-dev \ 
#       && git clone https://gitlab.com/rttopo/rttopo.git \
#       && cd rttopo && ./autogen.sh  && ./configure --enable-rttopo=yes --with-geosconfig=/usr/bin/geos-config  && make && make install   \
#       && cd \
 && apt-get install --yes gdal-bin  \
 && curl -LKS 'https://github.com/OpenDataDE/State-zip-code-GeoJSON/raw/master/ks_kansas_zip_codes_geo.min.json' -o  ks_kansas_zip_codes_geo.min.json \ 
 && ogrinfo --version \
 && ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -dialect sqlite -sql "select ST_MakeValid(geometry),STATEFP10,ZCTA5CE10,GEOID10,CLASSFP10,MTFCC10,FUNCSTAT10,ALAND10,AWATER10,INTPTLAT10,INTPTLON10,PARTFLG10 from \"ks_kansas_zip_codes_geo.min\"" clean.json ks_kansas_zip_codes_geo.min.json
```

Comment: Bounce. Same problem here. Using gdal 3.2.1 docker image and still no `ST_MakeValid()` function can be found in sqlite3 queries given to `ogr2ogr`.